# Printing values one by one

Tags: c#

i create simple get values and print the values in the printing statement it come without space,i want  it'll come one by one...

```
string s, n;
Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
s = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter your address");
n = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter your phonenumber");
int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter your Dob");
int p = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter your name:" + s + "Enter your address:" + n +         "Enter your phone number:" + m + "Enter your dob:" + p);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

use `Console.Writeline();` to give new line
 or use can use escape characters `\n`

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter your name\n");
```

or you can use `Environment.NewLine`

Answer (score 1):

**\n** Will goto a new Line

```
Console.WriteLine(" Enter your name \n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the below code..

```
Console.WriteLine("\n Enter your name:" + s + "\nEnter your address:" + n + "\nEnter your phone number:" + m + "\nEnter your dob:" + p);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your name:" + s + "\nEnter your address:" + n +"\nEnter your phone number:" + m + "\nEnter your dob:" + p);
```